# Tengo problemas con utf8 en PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, utf-8

Estoy trayéndome desde mysql datos que contienen caracteres especiales como ñ y tildes, el problema es que cuando los quiero mostrar por pantalla estos en vez de mostrarme la ñ o las tiles me muestra un signo de interrogación, ya intente hacer el set_charset("utf8") a mi conexión, a mi pagina HTMl también le agregue la etiqueta con el meta charset="UTF-8", y mi base de datos tiene el cotejamiento utf8mb4_unicode_ci, pero con todo lo anterior aun así no me muestra los caracteres especiales ya mencionado, a ver si me pueden ayudar, gracias!

Adjunto código de mi conexión en PHP:

```
<?php

   $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","practica");
   $conexion->set_charset("utf8"); 

?>
```

Archivo donde obtengo y muestro los datos obtenidos por pantalla:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        require("conexion.php"); 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios"; 
        $query=$conexion->query($sql);  
        

        while($fila = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $fila["apellido"]."<br>"; 
        }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Todos tenemos problemas con UTF-8... sin importar el lenguaje :-D

Comment: algo me dice que también vas a tener que indicar el charset encoding en los headers del response de PHP para que el cliente lo pueda entender bien.